# Using ampersand with an enumerator in a comparison

Tags: ruby

I have the following snippet that throws an error:

```
w = %w[ant dog]
w.all?(&:length > 4)
```

It throws an error `comparison of Symbol with 4 failed (ArgumentError)`.

I'm not sure why `&:length` is a symbol and not a number. I tried:

```
w.all?((&:length) > 4)
```

but that gives me a syntax error. Is there a way to get this to work or do I have to do: `w.all? { |word| word.length > 4 }`.

Comment: Because `&:length` is a symbol. You cannot pass functions that take *additional* arguments in this fashion. You can *create* a function that compares its input to `4` and pass *that* in, but all you can pass to functions expecting a process/block/method symbol is just that.

Answer (score 1):

You receive the following error, because the interpreter actually executes the following piece of code:

```
&:length > 4
```

and can't compare symbol `:length` with number `4`.

> Is there a way to get this to work or do I have to do: w.all? { |word| word.length > 4 }

You could do something like:

```
w.map(&:length).all? { |n| n > 4 }
```

But the following code is the simpliest way to go:

```
w.all? { |word| word.length > 4 }
```

Comment: yea, or even `[3, 3].all? { |n| n > 4 }`, but I just wanted to show, that you can create a reusable lambda and create a one-liner `w.map(&:length).all?(greater_than_four)`, but seems it appeared to be quite a vague idea

Comment: @CarySwoveland could reproduce it on Ruby <= 2.4.1. Since 2.5.0 seems fixed

Comment: To be precise, the ampersand hasn't come into play yet. The problem is simply with `:length > 4`. The ampersand would then apply to the result of it if that step had succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get this to work this way `w.all?(&:length > 4)`?

There is no way to make it work this way because it will require you to rewrite Ruby's interpreter.

> or do I have to do: `w.all? { |word| word.length > 4 }`

Yes, this is simple to read yet efficient way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had to hunt around a bit for a good technical answer to what's going on. [I found a thorough explanation here.](https://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/) The last section of that page explains what is happening in this particular case (but you should read the top part of the page as well).

Coming from Perl, I imagined the `&:length` was acting kind of like the `$_` variable. This is not correct.

What is happening is that instead of passing a block to the `all?` method, you are passing arguments to the `all?` method (note the parenthesis instead of curly braces). Here, we are passing the symbol for the method `length` as an argument to to `all?`. You put the `&` in front of the symbol to get it to call the `to_proc` method (whatever that is) on the `length` method so it can call the `length` function inside the `all?` method for each element.